# Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted on base64_encode

Tags: php, serialization, encoding

I am getting an "Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted" when I attempt to base64_encode a serialized array (it is long). Is there any recommended way to do this without running into this issue?

```
$_SESSION['stats'] = base64_encode(serialize($stats));
```

EDIT: Here is the actual error

```
Allowed memory size of 262144000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 34029660 bytes)
```

Comment: So how big is your $stats data, and how much memory does PHP have allocated and how much of your available memory are you using up to that point?

Comment: This is the error which includes the size: Allowed memory size of 262144000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 34029660 bytes)

Comment: Which tells me how much memory is assigned to PHP; but what about my other answers? How much memory is being used immediately prior to that line of code, and how big is $stats? The recommended answer is don't try to use more memory than you have available, but without knowing a lot more, then we can't give much more than that trite answer

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to put those in. Up until then it is using 172519544 bytes. I am not sure of the size of $stats unless it would be the "34029660" that I posted before.

Comment: The 34029660 may or may not be the size of $stats; it could be the size of stats after serialization.... why do you need to base64_encode though? that seems a redundant step, because it isn't necessary for storing in session, and is really bloating the size of data that you're trying to store in session

Comment: I don't know the original reason for doing it, I simply am maintaining the site since it was built by somebody else. The data is used to build a CSV file of all the searches made on the site to be downloaded by an administrator.

Comment: Well both the serialization and the base64_encoding will each perhaps double the memory requirement, and it appears to be a completely unnecessary step; but surely it would be better to store the csv file in the filesystem, not in session

Comment: That I completely agree with. I was simply hoping that there was an easier way that re-writing the functions.

Answer (score 1):

use this setting at the starting of your php script.This setting will allow php to exceed maximum amount of memory that each php script allowed to use.

```
<?php
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");

//Your remaining code..

?>
```

other links
https://drupal.org/node/207036

Comment: Removing the memory limit it's not probably the best solution, it could work but could also hide the real problem. Like a memory leak for example.